# Change link URL for logo in header on a SharePoint 2010 site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2007 I can go to site settings -> Look and Feel -> Top Link Bar
to set the url for the image link on all sites/subsites to point to the site collection site (or wherever I want).

How do I do this in SharePoint 2010, I can't find the menu option Top Link Bar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with coding and is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Title, description, and icon

That should control the top icon in a team site. What site template are you using?

**UPDATE**

Ah sorry you want the url to be changed. I dont think you can do that in the UI, but try accessing the page directly

_layouts/topnav.aspx

Comment: Hi djeeg, I couldn't find that page so I changed the NavigateUrl in the masterpage instead which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go and edit your master page(in sharepoint designer or if it is place on your vs) which you can find sharepoinnt icon tag like this

```
  <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage id="onetidHeadbnnr0"
 LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/titlegraphic.gif" runat="server"/>
```

change the LogoImageUrl to you Url.
hope this helps

gavrielse

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too late, but for all the others. Open the Masterpage with SharePoint Designer and change the NavigateUrl:

```
<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~SiteCollection/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic">
```